# Common Library in Sandbox Solution SharePoint 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, .net-4.5, sharepoint-2013

We have a solution structure like:

1. Project 1 (**Sandbox**)
2. Project 2 (**Farm**)
3. Project 3 (**Common Library, dll**)

Both Project 1 and Project 2 are using the Project 3 output dll for some functionality.
Everything was working fine on **SharePoint 2010 with .NET 3.5** (every project).

Now we have to migrate to SharePoint 2013 means we have to compile now with **.NET 4.5** and its new Security Level (no more CAS etc.)

The problem is that the Sandboxed Solution can not activate its feature because of errors like:

> "Namespace.Method" is security transparent, but is a member of a security critical type.

**Is it not possible to use a common library in sandboxed solution anymore?**

I tried to use the SecuritySafeCritical / SecurityCritical / AllowPartiallyTrust attributes and features but no combination could resolve the problem.
([No more CAS in 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5tk9z76%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: Side note: Since sandboxed solutions are deprecated in 2013, I'd personally look for a farm solution instead (unless you still have to deploy it into Office 365).

Comment: Know that, but there must be a Sandbox :( ... (if I were the decision maker there would be a farm solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the assemplyInfo.cs file add the line:

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
```

Deploy the Sandbox solution and then the Farm solution. Since both are referring your dll, the farm will successfully update the dll.

Comment: Have done that this way. Sorry for not self answering my question :)